# Resize columns width to fit content dynamically of JTable that it's inside of a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently using this [code](http://www.camick.com/java/source/TableColumnAdjuster.java) (taken from [here](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/)) to resize columns width, which is working, the table cells are not editable, the content is added dynamically using a DefaultTableModel, but if a row width is greater than the table, it doesn't use the scroll panel.

This is my table definition

```
JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
JTable jTable = new JTable();

jTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
   new Object [][] {
   },
         
   new String [] {
      "COLUMN1", "COLUMN2"
   }) {
      Class[] types = new Class [] {
         String.class, String.class
      };

      boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
         false, false
      };

      public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
         return types [columnIndex];
      }

      public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
         return canEdit [columnIndex];
      }
});

TableColumnAdjuster tblAdjuster = new TableColumnAdjuster(jTable);
tblAdjuster.setDynamicAdjustment(true);

jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable);
```

Are they any suggestions?

Comment: You only use 2 of the 3 lines of code needed to use the TableColumnAdjuster.

Comment: Which line am I omiting?

Comment: What does the example code from the link use?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what are you asking

Comment: The second link in your original question takes you to a blog entry. In the blog there are 3 lines of code that demonstrates the basic usage of the class. The code you posted does not use those 3 lines of code. The default behaviour of a JTable is to fit all the columns in the space available, so you will never see the scollbar of the scroll pane. The blog demonstrates how to change that behaviour. So my suggestion is to copy all 3 lines of code from the blog example.

Comment: Now I understand what did you try to say. However, I solved it by defining the AutoResizeMode to OFF as it says in the blog, my mistake. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it by following the rule defined by the developer of the code I used:

> Note, that this class was designed to be used with tables that use an
> auto resize mode of AUTO_RESIZE_OFF. With all other modes you are
> constrained, as the width of the columns must fit inside the table. So
> if you increase the width of one column, the widths of one or more of
> the other columns must decrease. Because of this, the resize mode of
> RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS will work the best.

So I have to set the AutoResizeMode to OFF before the creation of the TableColumnAdjuster instance:

```
jTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

Comment: This is exactly what the blog entry does. The point of my comments above was to make sure you pay attention to the information given in the blog. This is a question that should not have been posted in the forum. People spend time reading this, even though all the information needed to solve your problem was already given to you in the blog link. Don't just ignore code given in example unless you specifically know why you don't need the code.